# How to get property values from bundle manifest using BundleContext?

Tags: java, osgi, manifest

With my level of proficiency in OSGi, I can get property strings from:

1. BundleContext.getProperty(key) (stored in 'conf/config.properties')
2. ComponentContext.getProperties().get(key) (stored in bundle's 'MANIFEST.MF')

   Service-Component: \ foo.bar.impl.FixServer;application="quickfix.Application";properties:="acceptor.resourcename=acceptor.cfg"

I want to get properties in the bundle manifest, accessible at a bundle level (i.e. BundleContext), which is higher than 'Service-Component' (i.e. ComponentContext).

Can anyone show me how can this be done?

---

**ADDENDUM**

From the answers from AValchev and Neil Bartlett,

```
java.util.Dictionary headers = Bundle.getHeaders();
```

is a good approach.

**Edited 2011-12-10**

However, JAR Manifest syntax (requiring first char in the key to be uppercase, and '.' char disallowed) breaks my app key constants unless I do some refactoring.

If I do that, the app will break again should I use .properties file in the future.

To overcome the (IMO) 'limitation' of JAR Manifest Syntax, I have come up with this single manifest entry:

```
Bundle-Properties: \
foo.bar.prefix=MS,\
foo.bar.hostname=127.0.0.1,\
foo.bar.port=8106,\
foo.bar.homepath=/foo/bar/E3,\
foo.bar.secure=false,\
```

, and the code to digest the string into Properties:

```
java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
java.util.Dictionary headers = bcontext.getBundle().getHeaders();
String manifest_key = "Bundle-Properties";
String manifest_value = (String) headers.get(manifest_key);
if (manifest_value != null) {
    String[] t = manifest_value.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        String[] u = t[i].split("=");
        if (1 < u.length) {
            String key = u[0];
            String value = u[1];
            properties.setProperty(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what is your goal, but why you don't take a look at ConfigurationAdmin service, which is defined as OSGi standard.

One way of setting properties available to all bundles is with -Dproperty=value parameter in the command line. If you are using equinox, you can put your properties into config.ini.

What about the Bundle.getHeader(...) method? Just specify in your MANIFEST.MF file something like MY-Property: proper-value and then you can access it via Bundle.getHeader(). The problem with this approach is the naming convention required in MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Properties in bundle manifest are meant to be read-only and defined during bundle creation. To me, this is useful during deployment of updates.

Comment: What about the Bundle.getHeader(...) method? Just specify in your MANIFEST.MF file something like MY-Property: proper-value and then you can access it via Bundle.getHeader()

Comment: If you mean 'java.util.Dictionary headers = Bundle.getHeaders();', then yes, this would fit nicely. Could you revise your answer so I can tick it as answered?

Comment: Alas, Manifest format of 'KEY: VALUE' is breaking Properties' 'KEY=VALUE'.

Comment: Manifest key's first char must be uppercase. '.' char not allowed.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the drawbacks of this approach.

Comment: What comes into my mind is to use extender pattern which reads a property file "META-INF/config.properties" (for example) and sets everything from the property as system property (System.setProperty(..)

Comment: @AugustusThoo: Please bear in mind that the manifest format does not "break" properties format. It is simply *not in* properties format. It's not XML or JSON or anything else either. It's documented in the [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Manifest%20Specification) document.

Comment: I want to keep properties formatting from 'Service-Component' and move it up to 'Bundle-Properties'. My app that uses key constants influenced by most open sourced projects i.e. lower-case separated by dots. In context, I meant to say that it breaks my app, not some specs and ISOs.

Answer (score 4):

The title and body of your question do not match. The title asks how to *get* property values from the bundle manifest... this is easy:

```
Dictionary dict = bundleContext.getBundle().getHeader();
```

However the body of your question asks how to *set* property values in the manifest. This is not possible at runtime because the manifest is physically part of the bundle and cannot be dynamically modified.

If you're looking for some kind of bundle-level configuration data then consider using the Configuration Admin service.

Comment: Regarding your addendum, my only comment is that you appear determined to create more work for yourself than necessary!